# Error BadValueError: Virtual property is read-only

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In encountered the error

```
BadValueError: Virtual property is read-only
```

I have not found anything in the documentation about this error. What does it mean? Here's the relevant part of the code. It was working until a recent SDK update.

```
date = dt.datetime.strptime(self.json['birthday'],"%Y-%m-%d").date()
if self.json.has_key('avatar'):
    img = base64.b64decode(self.json['avatar'])
else:
    img = None
    log.info('No avatar')
user = db.User(
    name=self.json['name'], 
    password=self.json['password'], 
    full_name=self.json['full_name'],
    email = self.json['email'],
    birthday = date,
    avatar = img)
user.put()
```

Server logs

```
  File "/api/tornado/web.py", line 1064, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "user.py", line 31, in post
    avatar = img)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 970, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 615, in __set__
    setattr(model_instance, self._attr_name(), value)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 3874, in __set__
    raise BadValueError('Virtual property is read-only')
BadValueError: Virtual property is read-only
INFO     2013-06-08 07:44:37,776 server.py:585] default: "POST /api/user/create HTTP/1.1" 500 93
```

DB Model

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    full_name = db.StringProperty()    
    birthday = db.DateProperty()
    avatar = db.BlobProperty()
```

If I remove

```
avatar = img
```

then the error on the row above.

Comment: YOu going to beed to provide some more hints before you will get an answer.  Some code maybe, and stack trace.

Comment: `raise BadValueError('Virtual property is read-only')` as you see, it's a self-made error. I'd guess you're trying to write a read-only property. Try removing `avatar = img`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen no, see at my db model please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception comes from the `_ReverseReferenceProperty` class. This appears to be used when you have model with a `db.ReferenceProperty` pointing to it. You don't give enough details, but I suspect you have another model that uses `db.ReferenceProperty`, and you set `collection_name` to be the same name as one of the existing properties of User.

For example, if you had a model like this:

```
class Email(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name=email)
```

User.email would become read-only, and you would see that exception when you tried to set it. Search your other models to see if there is one with `db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name=...)`.

The error on `avatar = img)` is slightly misleading. That's just the last line of a multiline statement. It could be any part of that statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you missed is the following from the docs:

```
Blob is for binary data, such as images. **It takes a str value**, but this value
is stored as a byte string and is not encoded as text. Use a Text instance for 
large text data.
```

What you need to do is go through the following tutorial to upload a blob: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore

and in your model:

```
 avatar = db.BlobProperty() <-- you store the key to the uploaded avatar.
```

So in your model you simply store the key to the blob reference not the blob itself. I hope that is clear.

Also have a look at the following tutorial this one helped me a lot: https://gist.github.com/348025/d4fc873bda4a650210559f881738cc55a667ff2a

Comment: If I remove avatar = img, then the error on the row above. Blob nothing to do with